# incompatible types java.sql.timestamp cannot be converted to java.security.timestamp

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to fetch Data at what that Details has been added to my Database using Timestamp() but is show error of incompatible types java.sql.timestamp cannot be converted to java.security.timestamp

// Code User

```
package com.LearnCode.Entities;

import java.security.Timestamp;
import java.sql.*;


public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String gender;
    private String about;
    private Timestamp dateTime;
    private String profile;

    public User(int id, String name, String email, String password, String gender, String about, Timestamp dateTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.about = about;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String email, String password, String gender, String about) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.about = about;
        
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }

    public Timestamp getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }

    public void setDateTime(Timestamp dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public String getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(String profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }    
}
```

// Code DAO user
//incompatible types java.sql.timestamp cannot be converted to java.security.timestamp

```
public class UserDao {
    
    private Connection con;

    public UserDao(Connection con) {
        this.con = con;
    }
    
    // method to insert data of user in database
    
    public boolean saveUser(User user)
    {
        boolean f=false;
        try {
            
             String query = "insert into user(name,email,password,gender,about) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
             PreparedStatement pstmt = this.con.prepareStatement(query);
             pstmt.setString(1, user.getName());
             pstmt.setString(2, user.getEmail());
             pstmt.setString(3, user.getPassword());
             pstmt.setString(4, user.getGender());
             pstmt.setString(5, user.getAbout());
             
             pstmt.executeUpdate();
             f=true;
             
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return f;
    }
    
    // Get User by User E-Mail & Password
    
    public User getUserByEmailAndPassword(String email,String password)
    {
      User user=null;
      
      
        try {
            String query ="select * from user Where email=?,password=?";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, email);
            pstmt.setString(2, password);
            
            ResultSet set =pstmt.executeQuery();
            
            if(set.next())
            {
                user = new User();
             // Data From DB   
            String name = set.getString("name");
            //  Set in User Obj
            user.setName(name);
            
            user.setId(set.getInt("id"));
            user.setEmail(set.getString("email"));
            user.setPassword(set.getString("[password"));
            user.setGender(set.getString("gender"));
            user.setAbout(set.getString("about"));
            user.setDateTime(set.getTimestamp("regdate")); 
            user.setProfile(set.getString("profile"));
            
            }
           } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      
      
        return user;
      
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to be using `java.security.Timestamp`? If not, just change your import to `java.sql.timestamp` (or remove it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to use *java.security.TimeStamp* explicitly, you have to remove that import. If you need to use *java.security.TimeStamp* you can create one in DAO while setting *dateTime*. Replace following
`user.setDateTime(set.getTimestamp("regdate"));`
with
`user.setDateTime(new java.sql.TimeStamp(set.getTimestamp("regdate"), YOUR_CERT_PATH));`